# Acess Heroku variables from Flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have setup my database variables in the Heroku config using the following command

```
heroku config:add server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
heroku config:add user=userName 
heroku config:add password=pwd
heroku config:add database=dbName
```

How do I access these variables from my app.py file?

I have tried the following but no luck:

```
server = os.environ.get('server')
print server
exit()
```

this is returning nothing useful to the console when running `foreman start`

```
22:41:32 web.1  | started with pid 28844
22:41:32 web.1  | None
22:41:32 web.1  | exited with code 0
22:41:32 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Running `heroku config` shows me the correct variables.

Comment: Are you running `foreman start` locally? You'll only be able to access the Heroku config on Heroku. You'll want to use environment variables locally.

Comment: I'm not familar with flask but I have deployed a number of django web apps to heroku. In order for the django app to access the database, you `import dj_database_url; DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()`. This can be seen [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings). I believe you can also use this code to access heroku's database from the web app running locally, although it is much slower than calling a local database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your app locally, you can 'pull down' the Heroku environment variables by running:

```
heroku config:pull --overwrite
```

This will create a local `.env` file which contains your environment variables.

If you then run `$ source .env` in your terminal before running your app, these variables will be loaded into the environment for you -- in a manner similar to what Heroku does.

Also, your code looks incorrect.

The way you typically want to access environment variables is like so:

```
from os import environ

# If MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE doesn't exist, None will be printed.
print environ.get('MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE')
```