# os.environ.get() returns None for Heroku environmental variables

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

I have a few environment variables set up through Heroku to access a GrapheneDB instance. When I use the Heroku CLI command `heroku config`, all the environmental variables are returned as expected.

For example, `"heroku config"` returns:

```
GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD: some_password   
GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL:      bolt://hobby-someletters.dbs.graphenedb.com:24786
GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER:     appnumbers  
GRAPHENEDB_URL:           http://appnumbers:some_password@hobby-someletters.dbs.graphenedb.com:24789  
NEO4J_REST_URL:           GRAPHENEDB_URL
```

However, when I try to use the `os.environ.get()` method to access these environment variables, all three print statements return `None` rather than the desired output that the `heroku config` returns. This would indicate to me that the Python environment does not have access to the Heroku environment variables. How can I give python access to these?

```
import os
from py2neo import Graph

graphenedb_url = os.environ.get('GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL')
graphenedb_user = os.environ.get("GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER")
graphenedb_pass = os.environ.get("GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD")

print(graphenedb_url)
print(graphenedb_user)
print(graphenedb_pass)
```

I have tried using the solution from [Acess Heroku variables from Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035171/acess-heroku-variables-from-flask)
but when I do the command:
    `heroku config:pull --overwrite`
the CLI returns 
    `config:pull is not a heroku command.`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are executing a command ( other than `env` or something similar) to get those config variables it means that most likely they are NOT in your normal environment, meaning you can't get them through `os.environ.get()`.

What you can do would be to extract them from the output of that very command (the example - python 2.7 - assumes they come out on `stdout`, if they're not also check `stderr` in the same way):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

graphenedb_url = graphenedb_user = graphenedb_pass = None
stdout, stderr = Popen(['heroku', 'config'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
for line in stdout.split('\n'):
    split = line.split(':')
    if len(split) == 2:
        if split[0] == 'GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL':
            graphenedb_url = split[1].strip()
        elif split[0] == 'GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER':
            graphenedb_user = split[1].strip()
        elif split[0] == 'GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD':
            graphenedb_pass = split[1].strip()
print graphenedb_url
print graphenedb_user
print graphenedb_pass
```

Notes:

- the example is python 2.7
- it assumes the info comes out on `stdout`, if not check `stderr` as well, in the same way
- you may need to use the full path for the `heroku` executable, not sure.

Comment: This worked for me -- thank you!  But I do not understand the first paragraph of the answer.  I ran my app using the `heroku local` command, which you'd think would apply the correct environment, but it doesn't populate `os.environ` as I expect.

Comment: I meant that `env|grep GRAPHENEDB` won't show the vars, meaning they're not in the environment. Indeed, I'd also expect `heroku local` to set the environment pass it to the app launches.

Comment: Your comment helped my understanding -- thanks.  However, I must report that the workaround in the answer fails on Python apps deployed to Heroku, because Heroku does not permit shell commands.  I remain mystified why I can't get the Heroku "config" variables to be accessible via `os.environ`.

Comment: When you say that the variables "are NOT in your normal environment", what do you mean by "normal environment"? Where have those variables been defined? It seems really weird that such a workaround is needed for something as simple as loading env variables.

Comment: @DarksteelPenguin: I mean the env set by the normal shell execution (via .rc files) - if you need to execute a certain cmd to load them into the env.

Comment: Re: heroku -- there is this, which may prove helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035171/acess-heroku-variables-from-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1